# quickblox login authentication error in swift

Tags: quickblox

i am able to sign up but unble to log in in swift.

```
@IBAction func loginUser(_ sender : UIButton){


    QBRequest.logIn(withUserLogin: txtUserName.text!, password: txtPassword.text!, successBlock: { (response, user) in
         print("created user ::::",user)
    }) { (error) in
         print("created error")
    }

    }
```

i am getting below error.

```
 error: Request failed: unauthorized (401)
    reasons: {
        errors =     (
            "Unauthorized"
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Described in

https://quickblox.com/developers/Errors

You Might have entered Wrong Email/Password Or You Probably Using Invalid Token.